# The network name cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf-generation

For some reason I am receiving a The network name cannot be found. error when I try to apply the "myUniqueFileName" to the pdfwriter line. So its not a permissions issue because it works using the 1st code line below. Any ideas?

This works (Path is found)

```
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & "/Doc1.pdf", FileMode.Create))
```

This does not work

```
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))
```

This is complete code

```
    Dim Doc1 As New Document
    Dim path As String = "\\ServerAddress\PDFs"
    Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", Guid.NewGuid())
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))
    Doc1.Open()
    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))

    Doc1.Close()
```

Comment: Run this: `Dim combinedData As String = path & myUniqueFileName` and see what the string looks like while debugging.  I'm expecting there's some issues with escaped characters.

Comment: Thanks! looks like I needed to add a "\" at the end\\ServerAddress\PDFs\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Path.Combine, you are missing a backslash character when you are concatenating strings.

```
    Dim Doc1 As New Document
    Dim path As String = "\\ServerAddress\PDFs"
    Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", Guid.NewGuid())
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(path,myUniqueFileName), FileMode.Create))
    Doc1.Open()
    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))

    Doc1.Close()
```